# Separar primeros dos dígitos en una función, para luego operar con ellos

Tags: javascript

Necesito separar los dos primeros dígitos de un número para luego sumarle 1.

Por ejemplo, si en la función recibo 1980 necesito separar 19 para luego sumarle 1.

¿Alguna idea?

```
 function numero(año) {
        return año;
 }
```

Comment: No queda clara tu pregunta, ¿quieres siempre tomar los primeros dos dígitos y sumarle 1? ¿Que valor deberia retornar la función luego de ello, los dos primeros digitos o los cuatro dígitos?

Comment: si tomar los dos primeros digitos y sumarle uno eso es lo que retornaria

Comment: ¿Son sólo 4 dígitos o pueden variar?

Comment: solo 4 digitos, no varia.. para el ejemplo del numero el resultado es:20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de lograrlo sería utilizar [Math.floor(numero)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/floor) pasandole como parámetro el cociente entre el `año` y (asumiendo numeros de solo 4 dígitos) `100`

Esta función retorna el numero entero mas cercano y menor o igual al recibido por parámetro, por lo que el comportamiento sería análogo a realizar la [división entera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_eucl%C3%ADdea), quedándonos solo con el cociente despreciando el resto.

Dividiendo entre 100 un número de cuatro dígitos obtenemos un valor de 2 cifras enteras. Luego puedes sumarle 1.

```js
function numero(año) {
   var firstTwoDigits = Math.floor(año/100);
   return firstTwoDigits + 1;
}
console.log(numero(1980));
```

Otra alternativa, útil también para números de más dígitos, es convertir a `string` el `año`, tomar la subcadena desde el inicio hasta la posición 2, convertir ese valor a `number` y sumarle `1`.

```js
function numero(año) {
   var firstTwoDigits = año.toString().substring(0,2);
   return Number(firstTwoDigits) + 1;
}
console.log(numero(1980));
```